# What i need is first accordion inside one checkbox if checkbox is clicked the next accordion will automatically open

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm facing issue in bootstrap accordion..
What i need is first accordion inside one checkbox if checkbox is clicked the next accordion will automatically open, checkbox is not clicked the next accordion will not show

Any solution or reference please share

What i need is first accordion inside one checkbox if checkbox is clicked the next accordion will automatically open, checkbox is not clicked the next accordion will not show

Answer (score -2):

In order to achieve your desired functionality with Bootstrap accordion and checkboxes, you can use JavaScript to list checkbox changes events and then programmatically open or close the accordion based on the state of the checkbox. See example below;

HTML

```
 <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" />
      <label for="checkboxOne">Toggle Accordion One</label>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
      <div class="accordion-body">Content of Accordion One</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo" />
      <label for="checkboxTwo">Toggle Accordion Two</label>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
      <div class="accordion-body">Content of Accordion Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const checkboxOne = document.getElementById("checkboxOne");
    const checkboxTwo = document.getElementById("checkboxTwo");

    const collapseOne = document.getElementById("collapseOne");
    const collapseTwo = document.getElementById("collapseTwo");

    checkboxOne.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            collapseOne.classList.add("show")''
        } else {
            collapseOne.classList.remove("show");
        }
    });

    checkboxTwo.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            collapseTwo.classList.add("show")''
        } else {
            collapseTwo.classList.remove("show");
        }
    });
});
```

In the example above, each one of the accordion items has a checkbox and a label. The script attaches event listeners to the checkboxes and when a checkbox is checked, the relevant accordion is shown by adding the core bootstrap class `show`. Also when the checkbox is unchecked, the bootstrap class `show` is removed from the classes and this hides the accordion. Hope this helps or points you in the right direction, cheers!